# defined properties are not created normally in Breeze

Tags: breeze

in my project I defined properties in my Ctor

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'DTasks', {
        get: function() {
            return handlePropertyGet('_dtasks', "DTasks");
        },
        set: function(value) { //used only when loading incidents from the server
            handlePropertySet('DTask', value);
        },
        enumerable: true
    });
```

how ever in the new version of breeze - the addition of use strict really deletes the property so there is a need to add configuralbe: true. But this property is "recreated" in the backingStore and to the value of this property a results field is added. What is the best way to define property in breeze? as this property dont need to be in the backingStore as it isn't mapped one, so maybe to define it in the initialize of the type? As I am working with Microsoft OData which lacks the correct config of the navigation property, I am using those properties for the population of the expand

Answer (score 0):

When you use ES5 Defined Properties for your unmapped properties, Breeze will assume that you want to attach behaviors (such as change tracking, validation, etc) to the setters. This is why Breeze will add the properties to the backingStore. If you want to define them without telling Breeze to track them, you can use the post-construction initializer technique.

```
var customerInitializer = function(customer) {
    customer.isBeingEdited = ko.observable(false);

    //or just customer.isBeingEdited = false, if you're using Angular
};

metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Customer', null, customerInitializer);
```

You can read more details about the different ways to extend your entities at http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities

Hope this helps.